# Finding the minimum value out of all the outcomes of a predicate

Tags: prolog, minimum

I have the following predicates:

```
slow(a , 10 , b).
slow(b , 17 , c).
slow(c , 12 , d).
slow(d , 19 , e).
slow(e , 13 , f).

fast(a , 20 , c).
fast(b , 20 , d).
fast(d , 20 , f).

line(X,T,Y) :- slow(X,T,Y).
line(X,T,Y) :- fast(X,T,Y).

journey(X,N,Z) :-
    line(X,L,Y),
    journey(Y,M,Z),
    N is L+M.
journey(X,0,X) :-
    !.
```

I now need to create a new predicate of 2arity to find the minimum value of N defined in the journey predicate.

I've so far defined the new predicate as:

```
minimum(X,Y) :-
    journey(X,N,Y),
    write(N).
```

I've tried to use findall/3 and bagof/3 to make a list and find the minimum atom of that list, but I am not sure how to use them.

I'm not sure how else to go about it, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(First, remove the !)

```
?- journey(A,N,B), false.
   false.           % your definition always terminates, good
?- journey(A,N,B), \+ ( journey(A,M,B), M < N ).
   A = a, N = 49, B = e
;  A = a, N = 50, B = f
;  A = a, N = 30, B = d
;  A = a, N = 10, B = b
;  A = b, N = 17, B = c
;  A = c, N = 31, B = e
;  ... .
?- setof(N,journey(A,N,B),[N|_]).
   N = 0, A = B
;  N = 10, A = a, B = b
;  N = 20, A = a, B = c
;  N = 30, A = a, B = d
;  N = 49, A = a, B = e
;  N = 50, A = a, B = f
;  N = 17, A = b, B = c
;  ... .
?- setof(N,journey(A,N,B),[N|_]), journey(A,N,B).
   ... . % same as above but in general safer
```